# Написать Sql запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
----------------------------
|id|city|managerid|lastname|
----------------------------
```

Вывести фамилии всех работников с таблицы hr.employees и города их проживания, менеджеры которых проживают в лондоне.

Cуть в том, что менеджеры и работники - в одной таблице. То есть например работник с id 2 может быть менеджером для работника с id 1, если managerid для него равен 2.

Comment: ну а где у вас хранятся города проживания менеджеров?

Comment: city. суть в том, что менеджеры и работники - в одной таблице. То есть например работник с id 2 может быть менеджером для работника с id 1, если managerid для него равен 2.

Comment: SELECT `emp`.`lastname`, `emp`.`city` FROM `hr.employees` as `emp` WHERE `emp`.`managerid` > 0 AND (SELECT `city` FROM `hr.employees` WHERE `id` = `emp`.`managerid`) = 'London'

Comment: должно работать

Comment: >>emp.managerid > 0
А это зачем? почему не может быть отрицательного айди?(в задании ни слова) или нулевым? 
У меня иногда проскакивает - пользователь ноль - пользователь по умолчанию(аки Гость), тут может быть мэнеджер по умолчанию - 0, и у него может быть город "ландан" =)

Comment: вряд ли у менеджера может быть менеджер. если `managerid > 0`, то он работник. P.S. нужно основываться на тайп `managerid`, выше я описал случай, если тайп `managerid` = `int` и стоит по умолчанию 0, как обычно это и делается

Comment: Т.е. с деревьями вы не сталкивались?( когда у отдела есть руководитель, а у руководителя отдела есть руководитель подразделения? и так дальше по цепочке... =) Мэнеджер - не продажник, как многим въелось в сознание, а именно управленец =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select 
  f1.city,
  f1.lastname,
  f1.city
from 
  hr.employees f1
  inner join hr.employees f2 on ((f1.managerid = f2.id) and (f2.city='london'));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз то, что нужно.

Comment: Если задача не учебная - советую поиграть с местоположением условий объединения =) иногда существенно прибавляет скорости на больших таблицах =)